# What is a lambda language?

Tags: javascript, lambda

I was reading "JavaScript: The Good Parts" and the author mentions that JavaScript is the first of the lambda languages to be launched.

> JavaScript's functions are first class objects with (mostly) lexical scoping. JavaScript is the first **lambda language** to go mainstream. Deep down, JavaScript has more in common with Lisp and Scheme than with Java. It is Lisp in C's clothing. This makes JavaScript is remarkably powerful language.

I didn't get what is a lambda language. What are the properties of such a language and how is it different from languages like Java, C, C++ and Php?

Comment: Lambda means anonymous expression. So lambda language -> language with anonymous expressions

Comment: Google Books link, FYI: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=lambda+language+crockford&source=bl&ots=HHtnnar4jI&sig=EmkjJCBHLOn5shPtgKzaZ_tQ4xg&hl=en&ei=okirTMyYGoqQjAfxuL3qBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=lambda%20language&f=false

Comment: See [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) on wikipedia.

Comment: many good replies. What i understood by far is if you are using anonymous function then u are working on lambda language. is that correct understanding how diffrent are lamda languages from language like java.

Comment: "I was reading 'JavaScript: The Good Parts' and the author mentions that JavaScript is the first of the lambda languages to be launched." So I googled lambda language and found this question on SO :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've never heard anyone use the term "lambda language," and the only plausible definitions I can think of would exclude JavaScript as "the first."

That said, I suspect he may mean either:

- Functional languages: a class of languages in  which computation is (or can be) modeled as a stateless composition of (possibly higher-order) functions. LISP, Scheme, ML, Haskell, etc. are frequently ascribed to this class, although several of these are more properly mixed paradigm or "functional optional" languages. Javascript arguably contains the necessary features to make a "functional style" of programming possible.
- Languages which allow the creation of anonymous functions (using the `function` syntax in JavaScript; this is written `lambda` in many languages, hence possibly "lambda languages."

Both usages are derived from the use of the greek letter lambda to denote function abstraction in the lambda calculus, the model of computation devised by Alonzo Church and upon which functional programming is based.

Edit: looked at Google Books result---"first to go mainstream"; well, that's arguable. I'd put forward that LISP was at one point at least reasonably mainstream. It's a fair point though, JavaScript's semantics are directly inspired by Scheme and it certainly reached a larger audience than any other language that can make similar claims.

Comment: please see the link posted by Lucas Jones Google book link where he takes to the exact page i am talking about. thanks for ur answer.

Comment: The reason JavaScript is described as being 'the first' is because the statement is qualified with 'to go mainstream'. I think it's pretty clear that JavaScript is indeed the first functional-style language to be used by every-day programmers at every-day jobs.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "functional-style" of programming language. I am from a java background and trying to learn javascript how is it different.

Comment: @Derrick please explain "Functional languages: a class of languages in which computation is (or can be) modeled as a stateless composition of (possibly higher-order) functions"

Comment: It's a huge topic to explore. Last year I was where you are now: I had found Crockford's essays and lectures and wanted to understand closures. I would recommend you start with Wikipedia, then move on to a few essays: John Hughes "Why Functional Programming Matters" http://www.scribd.com/doc/26902/whyfp, Slava Akhmechet "Functional Programming for the rest of us" http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/fp.html There is a wealth of books to expand your mind: check out the Little Schemer to get a feel for Scheme, and then move on to the Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs.

Comment: Of course, there are also loads of questions on SO with great explanations on closures, lambda expressions, etc ...

Comment: @spacemanaki I wish i would be able to keep clicking upvotes for posting all the links many thanks for ur posts...

Comment: @sushil: there's a lot of introductory literature on the topic. In general terms though, it's a style of programming that emphasizes treating programs as mathematical objects rather than sequential instructions or interactions between abstract objects. For example, functional languages will prefer recursion to iteration, make use of immutable data structures, and use higher-order functions in preference to "function objects" or "strategy patterns". Higher-order functions meaning functions which may operate on (as arguments) or yield (as return values) other functions.

Answer (score 49):

A lambda language, in simple terms, is a language that allows passing a function to another function,  where the function is treated as any other variable. Also, you should be able to define this function to be passed anonymously (or inline). PHP 5.3 added support for lambda functions. Was JavaScript the first mainstream language? Lisp has been widely used in educational settings before JavaScript and also in customizing our beloved Emacs http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/

Here's an example

```
function applyOperation(a, b, operation) {
  return operation(a,b);
}

function add(a,b) { return a+ b; }
function subtract(a,b) {return a - b;}

// Can be called like
applyOperation(1,2, add);
applyOperation(4,5, subtract);
// Anonymous inline function
applyOperation(4,7, function(a,b) {return a * b})
```

How is it different from C? In C, you can pass pointer to functions, but you can't define it inline anonymously.

In Java (before version 8), to achieve the same effect, you must pass an object that implements an interface, which actually can be defined anonymously inline.

Comment: "Lisp has been widely used" by whom?  I've always known about it, since professors would always discuss it, but in practice, I've never met anyone who has used Lisp.  I would say that anyone could find someone they know who has used Javascript, which makes Javascript much more "mainstream".

Comment: "PHP 5 added support for lambda functions". Actually iy was PHP 5.3 that introduced lambda functions.

Comment: I've met few people that used it in a business context, but like Pascal once was, it's widely used in educational settings.

Answer (score 4):

He refers to [Lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

> Lambda calculus, also written as λ-calculus, is a formal system for function definition, function application and recursion.
>   [...]
>
> [...] with untyped lambda calculus being the original inspiration for functional programming, in particular Lisp, and typed lambda calculi serving as the foundation for modern type systems.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a lambda defined as an anonymous function and as a reference to a function.  Javascript supports both:

```
setTimeout(function(){ /* an anonymous function */ }, 100)

var f = function(){ /* function ref */ }
```

This is where JS gets a lot of its power and flexibility.  Java supports the first to some extent (anonymous interface implementations), <strike>but not the latter</strike> - see below for update for Java 8.

Its unclear to me which (or both) of these is the proper definition of a lambda.

JS is definitely not the first language to support these features.  Going from memory, I think its smalltalk that language enthusiasts always rave about supporting lambdas.

BTW: In Java, an anonymous class is usually used to pass in a class definition on the fly for an argument (used a lot in swing).  Something like this (from memory, not compiled):

```
someGuiContainer(new WidgetInterface()
      {
           public void importantMethodToDefine(){
             // Handle having the method called in my special widget way
           }
        }
)
```

---

*Update*

Java, as of 8, is now officially a Lambda language.

You can now use the following syntax:

```
MathOperation addition = (int a, int b) -> a + b;
System.out.println("10 + 5 = " + tester.operate(10, 5, addition));
```

[Code Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_lambda_expressions.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In MIT's open course-ware called structure and interpretation of computer programs a book by Hal Abelson's, Jerry Sussman's and Julie Sussman's. They discuss Scheme, which is a dialect of LISP and there they explain a very detailed and clear explanation of what lambda is and Scheme LISP and languages in general. I highly recommend you look at it if you wish to have a really clear and deep understanding of Computer Programming. To explain to you would take three times as much time as if you went there and just read the book or watch the tutorials which explains it perfectly, it's genius.

Javascript is mainly based off of the language Scheme and it's Lisp father, and in addition it took its lamda structure and went mainstream with it.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:
In programming languages such as Lisp and Python, lambda is an operator used to denote anonymous functions or closures, following the usage of lambda calculus. An example of this use of lambda in the Python language is this section of computer code that sorts a list alphabetically by the last character of each entry:

```
>>> list = ['woman', 'man', 'horse', 'boat', 'plane', 'dog']
>>> sorted(list, key=lambda word: word[-1])
['horse', 'plane', 'dog', 'woman', 'man', 'boat']

* In the C# programming language a lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements
```

Answer (score 0):

- JavaScript allows to define Anonymous function that is a function which is not bound to an identifier. Such function is also known as Lambda Abstraction and since JS support this it is known as Lambda Language.
- Properties : This function are needed in case of immediate execution of a function or for short term use, where there is no significance of giving name to function.
- It is different from languages like Java, C, C++ and PHP as in JS Anonymous functions are used for Closure and Currying.